# How do I spin up an embedded kafka cluster during my test?

Tags: java, junit, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

To test how our spring boot application handles it when the kafka cluster is not yet up, I would like to spin up an embedded kafka cluster in a junit test some time after the application starts up. How could I approach this?
As I understand it spring-kafka-test's `@EmbeddedKafka` starts up the cluster before creating the application context of a SpringBootTest. Is there any way to configure that timing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defined as a bean (via `@EmbeddedKafka`) or as a JUnit condition (again via `@EmbeddedKafka` - when there is no test Spring ApplicationContext), the broker is started in `afterPropertiesSet()`.

You should be able to create the broker manually and call `afterPropertiesSet()` whenever you are ready.

Here is the code from the JUnit5 `EmbeddedkafkaCondition`:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private EmbeddedKafkaBroker createBroker(EmbeddedKafka embedded) {
    EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker;
    int[] ports = setupPorts(embedded);
    broker = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(embedded.count(), embedded.controlledShutdown(),
                    embedded.partitions(), embedded.topics())
            .zkPort(embedded.zookeeperPort())
            .kafkaPorts(ports)
            .zkConnectionTimeout(embedded.zkConnectionTimeout())
            .zkSessionTimeout(embedded.zkSessionTimeout());
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    for (String pair : embedded.brokerProperties()) {
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(pair)) {
            continue;
        }
        try {
            properties.load(new StringReader(pair));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to load broker property from [" + pair + "]",
                    ex);
        }
    }
    if (StringUtils.hasText(embedded.brokerPropertiesLocation())) {
        Resource propertiesResource = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
                .getResource(embedded.brokerPropertiesLocation());
        if (!propertiesResource.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Failed to load broker properties from [" + propertiesResource
                            + "]: resource does not exist.");
        }
        try (InputStream in = propertiesResource.getInputStream()) {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.load(in);
            p.forEach(properties::putIfAbsent);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Failed to load broker properties from [" + propertiesResource + "]", ex);
        }
    }
    broker.brokerProperties((Map<String, String>) (Map<?, ?>) properties);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(embedded.bootstrapServersProperty())) {
        broker.brokerListProperty(embedded.bootstrapServersProperty());
    }
    broker.afterPropertiesSet();
    return broker;
}
```